# PHP/MySQL : How to use PDO within the structure of an MVC to populate view?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I was just having some trouble in how to structure my code within the MVC architecture and use it to populate a table. I am a beginner so please go easy.  The code i have at the moment for this specific query is as follows :

Controller

```
<?php
require_once ("models/database.php");

class Payment extends Controller {

function __construct() {

    include("views/payment.php");

}

}
```

Model (database.php)

```
public static function payment ()
{
    $conn = self::get_connection();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT fr.shopid, SUM( p.amount)"
. "FROM frs_FilmRental AS fr"
. "JOIN frs_Payment as p ON fr.payid = p.payid"
. "GROUP BY shopid"
. "LIMIT 0 , 30");

    $stmt->execute();
    $shop = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $conn=null;
    return $shop;

}
```

View

```
 foreach($shop as $row) {
  echo
      "<td width = 100 align = center>" . $row ["shopid"] .
      "<td width = 100 align = center>" . $row["shopname"] .
      "<td width = 200 align = center>" . $row["total"] .
      "</td></tr>";
 }
```

At the moment i am getting 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach() '

Comment: I haven't used MVC without a framework but try add in your controller just before you include the payment.php
`$db = new database(); $shop = $db::payment();` Assuming database.php is a class named database and in that class is your static payment method.
 That should call the static function payment in database.php and assign it to the variable $shop for your view to use.